# Load testing ec2 Node.js with Apache AB - 6500 QPS run on server but 175 QPS from remote

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, load-testing

I am trying to load test a simple node.js and cyclone hello world app on an ec2 c1.xlarge machine on ubuntu 64.  It has 8 cores.  I am using nginx as a load balancer and supervisor is launching one process for each core.  When I run the below on the machine, My qps is about 6500 for node.js.

```
 ab -n 5000 -c 25 http://127.0.0.1
```

When I run ab from a remote machine, even a machine that is in the same zone, qps drops to about 175 qps.  Its even worse if I run from my dev machine.

So, what am I missing?  Are there parameters that I have to tune to allow for more connections from remote machines?  I feel I am missing something.  Is there a magic nob I have to tune in the sysctl config file?  Its a rather raw machine but on boot, the below are the nobs that I tune.

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=128000;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300;
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=250000;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2500;
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=30000;
sysctl -p
```

Comment: Could it be that the network really is the bottleneck here?

Comment: Well...the 175 QPS was on an ec2 in the same placement group.  That means right next to each other.

Comment: Highly optimized software can easily process more requests per time than a 100 Mbit/s ethernet interconnect can transport. You should have an estimate of how much bandwidth your benchmark uses on localhost. Comparing this to the interconnect bandwidth between nodes in a placement group of EC2 will tell us if the network can be the bottleneck.

Comment: Hm, I've just read "All instances launched within a Placement Group have low latency, full bisection 10 Gbps bandwidth between instances". So, assuming Amazon has no network problems, it's pretty unlikely that the NIC is responsible for this significant drop in performance.

Comment: So...I am rather new to this....so...what do I do?  Its a hello world app. It should be fast.

Comment: Just to be sure, benchmark the network itself between the two nodes. This can be done in various ways. A very simple one is a combination of `dd` and `netcat`, as described here: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Benchmark

Comment: Then, during your webserver benchmark, monitor the bandwidth usage, using for example BWM-NG: http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng

Comment: You should put your "server" under load from various remote "clients" simultaneously. This minimizes the impact of client performance and and client network bandwidth on the benchmark result. At the same time, you should monitor the network bandwidth on the server side in order to make sure you do not saturate the server's NIC. This should provide conclusive performance data of your server application under heavy load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latency is slowing the test down which reduces throughput. In virtually every case, a remote request is going to take longer than a local one so a single thread will have a lower throughput running remotely than when running locally and thus, when using Ab which will not pace requests, the overall throughput must decrease.

For example, you have 25 threads. Lets say it takes 50ms to make your request locally. For one thread this gives:

1000 (1 second) / 50 = 20 requests per/sec - this is the maximum throughput possible with one thread.

Over 25 theads that adds up to 25 * 20 = 500 req/s.

If you take that formula and change the response time to, say, 250ms then the total *maximum* throughput for on thread drops to 4 req/s giving an overall maximum possible with 25 threads of 80 requests per second.

Taking this a step further: If you say you get 6000 qps with 25 threads then logically your app responds in about 4ms when called locally. If you can only get 175 qps remotely then it is because the response time drops to about 142ms, so in your system you have latency of about 138ms - give or take - and this is the issue.

Comment: I am still rather confused.  So..if I get e.g. 4000  requests for different machines, then I am ok?  So, whan people report qps from AB load tests, this is why its done on the server?  Rather than remote machines?

Comment: The results you get locally are a representation of what your app can achieve in isolation. This is what Ab is good at. If you want a more thorough load test incorporating each tier of the system then, well, it's a lot more work. I think though that for your purposes your value of 4000 holds true in this context. You might even find you can get even greater qps using more threads.

Comment: If you did want to extend you load testing then you'll probably want to upgrade from Ab to JMeter, both Apache projects but JMeter has considerably more functionality.

Comment: I disagree with your argumentation, Oliver. You're right about the 4 ms local response time. But as long as Tampa is not providing a latency benchmark, I strongly doubt that more than 100 ms per request "are lost" due to network latency: Tampa's machines have a 10 Gbps interconnect. The latency in such an ethernet shouldn't be more than a couple of ms.

Comment: Right but the reason the OP has lower throughput is because he has slower response times. This is the answer to the question.